# Efficient method for using formulas in a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

I am trying to add a column to a dataframe based on a formula. I don't think my current solution is very pythonic/efficient. So I am looking for faster options.

**I have a table with 3 columns**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
 [1,1,20.0],
 [1,2,50.0],
 [1,3,30.0],
 [2,1,30.0],
 [2,2,40.0],
 [2,3,30.0],
], 
columns=['seg', 'reach', 'len']
) 

# print df
df
    seg  reach   len
  0   1      1  20.0
  1   1      2  50.0
  2   1      3  30.0
  3   2      1  30.0
  4   2      2  40.0
  5   2      3  30.0

# Formula here
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['reach'] ==1:
        df.ix[index,'cumseglen'] = row['len'] * 0.5
    else:
        df.ix[index,'cumseglen'] = df.ix[index-1,'cumseglen'] +  0.5 *(df.ix[index-1,'len'] + row['len'])

#print final results
df
  seg   reach    len    cumseglen
0   1       1   20.0    10.0
1   1       2   50.0    45.0
2   1       3   30.0    85.0
3   2       1   30.0    15.0
4   2       2   40.0    50.0
5   2       3   30.0    85.0
```

**How can I improve the efficiency of the formula step?**

Answer (score 2):

To me this looks like a group-by operation. That is, within each "segment" group, you want to apply some operation to that group.

Here's one way to perform your calculation from above, using a group-by and some cumulative sums within each group:

```
import numpy as np

def cumulate(group):
    cuml = 0.5 * np.cumsum(group)
    return cuml + cuml.shift(1).fillna(0)

df['cumseglen'] = df.groupby('seg')['len'].apply(cumulate)
print(df)
```

The result:

```
   seg  reach   len  cumseglen
0    1      1  20.0       10.0
1    1      2  50.0       45.0
2    1      3  30.0       85.0
3    2      1  30.0       15.0
4    2      2  40.0       50.0
5    2      3  30.0       85.0
```

Algorithmically, this is not exactly the same as what you wrote, but under the assumption that the "reach" column starts from 1 at the beginning of each new segment indicated by the "seg" column, this should work.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense.